# How to perform a count statistics without wait for ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, redirect

I want to count number of click to particular div(`#counter`) and then redirect to a different site.

I did a ajax call on click event of the div with the id `counter`. and then on success function i'm doing a redirect on ajax complete. Here is the code

```
jQuery('#counter').click(function(){
  var data = { clicked:'yes'
};

jQuery.ajax({
  url:"stat.php",
  type:"POST",
  data:data
}).done(function(res){
    window.location = "http://www.myurl.com";
  });    
});
```

The thing is, this is making some time to redirect such that user have to wait until the ajax complete event trigger.

Since am not care of the response i just need a request that initiates user has clicked that(`#counter`) div so i'll just increment the value in DB. So is there a way to redirect to a different website as soon as the ajax started? I don't want the user to wait for the response and then redirect. because the response is not needed in this case. This is only for site stat or what is the best way to count a button click and then redirect them to a different site.

Comment: If you don't wait for the ajax to complete and the user leaves that page, the request will be `ERR_ABORT` and it won't complete.

Comment: So. Must i wait? Can't i leave as soon as request sent?

Comment: Correct. If you perform the ajax call and then a window.location redirect directly after (instead of within the .done deferral), then the ajax request (if not completed) will result in an `ERR_ABORT`, which will terminate the request to the server and end the lifecycle on the HTTPD thread that spawned this request.

Comment: @rram: it's the equivalent of going through a drivethrough window, ordering your cheeseburger, then driving away without waiting. you never get your cheeseburger and the restaurant's just going to throw it in the trash because you're no longer in the drivethrough to receive it.

Comment: How long is it taking? Such simple request should be really fast, even for a user across the globe... Is opening on a new tab/window an option?

Comment: could you pass the url you want to go to to your server along with the data, have the serve record the click then redirect the user

Comment: Okay i'll take @Andre advice. I'll open the link in new tab. Is it okay?

Answer (score 1):

Edit, updated

Try

```
jQuery('#counter').click(function(){
   data = { clicked:'yes'
   };
   var redirect = function() {
       setTimeout(function() {
     window.top.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/"
                                + "25554598/"
                                + "how-to-perform-a-count-statistics-"
                                + "without-wait-for-ajax-response/";
       }, 1500); };
   $.when(jQuery.ajax({
       url:"/echo/json/",
       type:"POST",
       data:{json:JSON.stringify(data)}
   }), redirect())
   .done(function(_data) {
     alert(_data[0].clicked)
   })   
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/51g5huvq/

Comment: This will redirect for all ajax call from my site. I want to do it only for #counter click. Also am not sure as above guys said it will trash the ajax request.

Comment: Have you tested? I doubt it will work, as the browser will redirect before and never complete the ajax request...

Comment: Yes yours works. +1 But how to redirect only on particular div click. Also could you tell, is this also redirecting only after getting ajax call response? Because i can see that the ajax request is completed in the browser console. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just move your redirect code outside of the .done callback. This way, when you click, two things are instantly done : an ajax request is sent, and the redirection is fired. You can wrap the redirection in a short setTimeout to make sure the ajax request has been fired before redirecting the client.

```
jQuery('#counter').click(function(){
   var data = { clicked:'yes'
   };
   jQuery.ajax({
       url:"stat.php",
       type:"POST",
       data:data
   }).done(function(res){

   });    
   setTimeout(function(){window.location = "http://www.myurl.com";}, 500);
});
```